# PHP/MySQL Need to merge data from two tables to one object and sort them by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, merge

I have two tables in my DB. One for one kind of items, second for another kind of items (some columns are same, some are different, first table contains 23 columns, second one contains 24 columns). Users can add these two kind of items. I somehow need to mere all these items and sort them by date (timestamp column), so most recently add items are shown first. Items are offers and demands (student accomodation).

Right now, I use two sql queries and offers are first (sorted by date) and then demands (sorted by date). But this system is bad, because with many items, users will have to go through many pages, before they find demand. So i need it to be combined.

Part of my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){
    ...
}}

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM table2 ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql1)) {
    while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){
    ...
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use union all in query 
check out it

```
SELECT  *

FROM (SELECT * FROM table1  WHERE "condition" UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2 )

ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: UNION can be used to unite tables with different number of columns?

Comment: yes you can union two tables if there is different column but there is one column should be common

Comment: This throws #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: The UNION and UNION ALL operators require that:

    The same number of columns exist in all the statements that make up the UNION'd query***You were selecting 4 in the first query and 6 in the second, so match them up.
    The data types have to match at each position/column

Comment: Problem is, that I need different columns for demands and other for offers

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
  SELECT * FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM table2) raw
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

You should define the same column names and order to let them be unioned.

Comment: This throws #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns  :-(

Comment: define which columns should be included in the result dataset and choose them instead of *

Comment: I need different columns for offers and different for demands :-/

Comment: create as many columns as you need. In each ssection of the UNION add missing columns with some default values (e.g. NULLs)